# Java and database connection

Tags: java, sql, database

I'm trying to write a java program that stores data in an independent sql db. However, I have no idea about how to create a sql db with java and how to make this connection. Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: Google is your best friend..

Comment: [See this link](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20and%20sql)

Comment: I don't know any jargon about this topic. And google shows a lot of different ideas and I'm not sure which one to pick up.

Comment: You have plenty of links in [SO JDBC wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jdbc/info)

Answer (score 2):

Add [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) to your classpath, and it's as simple as:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Jdbc {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.execute("create table chair(id int primary key auto_increment, legs int not null, color varchar(255))");
        statement.execute("insert into chair (legs, color) values (4, 'red')");
        statement.execute("insert into chair (legs) values (6)");
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from chair");
        while (rs.next()) {
            String color = rs.getString("color") == null ? "" : rs.getString("color") + " ";
            System.out.println("Got a " + color + "chair with " + rs.getInt("legs") + " legs");
        }
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

Aside from being able to run purely in memory or as a standalone server, H2 also comes with a built-in, web-based sql workbench.

Note: You should start out with the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) to help you avoid the major pitfalls, like connection leaks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/)?

> Apache Derby, an Apache DB subproject, is an open source relational
>   database implemented entirely in Java and available under the Apache
>   License, Version 2.0. Some key advantages include:
>
> - Derby has a small footprint -- about 2.6 megabytes for the base engine and embedded JDBC driver.
> - Derby is based on the Java, JDBC, and SQL standards.
> - Derby provides an embedded JDBC driver that lets you embed Derby in any Java-based solution.
> - Derby also supports the more familiar client/server mode with the Derby Network Client JDBC driver and Derby Network Server.
> - Derby is easy to install, deploy, and use.
>
> If you're new to Derby, check out the Quick Start page.

This said, I forgot about H2.  +1 for Ryan's suggestion.